# calculate the cumulative % of a hierarchy member in icCube | TopPercent but than different

Tags: mdx, iccube

With the function TopPerent, you can get the set of members - ordered top down - that comply to the % value provided.

I would like to switch this function and get the cumulative % given the member.

[image: TopPercent in icCube, all countries in Excel ordered top down on Amount. Cum % caluclated. The BLUE highlighted values indicate the value I would like to obtain]

Description of the image:
TopPercent in icCube, all countries in Excel ordered top down on Amount. Cum % caluclated. The BLUE highlighted values indicate the value I would like to obtain

Comment: Do you need Cum % MDX version, right?

Comment: Yes, but I also found an answer. I do not know it it the best, but it works.

Comment: Correction --> I found an answer to my original question that I did not post here. I could not answer this specific question, I just found another way to calculate what I needed. I am still curious on how to calculate this.

Comment: (upped) very good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope it will be enough to understand the point:

```
With 
Set [OrderedCity] as
Order([Customer].[City].[City].Members,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],DESC)    

Member [Measures].[Cum] as
Sum(    
    Head([OrderedCity],Rank([Customer].[City].CurrentMember,[OrderedCity])),
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
)

Member [Measures].[Cum %] as
[Measures].[Cum] / ([Customer].[City].[All],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]),
Format_String = "Percent"

Select
Non Empty [OrderedCity] on 1,
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[Cum],[Measures].[Cum %]} on 0
From [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: (upped) very nice answer